# golang, call GetVolumeInformation winapi function

Tags: winapi, go

Tries to call GetVolumeInformation function from golang. Want to get volume name.

Use spec's of api:

```
BOOL WINAPI GetVolumeInformation(
  _In_opt_  LPCTSTR lpRootPathName,
  _Out_opt_ LPTSTR  lpVolumeNameBuffer,
  _In_      DWORD   nVolumeNameSize,
  _Out_opt_ LPDWORD lpVolumeSerialNumber,
  _Out_opt_ LPDWORD lpMaximumComponentLength,
  _Out_opt_ LPDWORD lpFileSystemFlags,
  _Out_opt_ LPTSTR  lpFileSystemNameBuffer,
  _In_      DWORD   nFileSystemNameSize
);
```

Use code:

```
// test
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    var lpRootPathName = "C:\\"
    var lpVolumeNameBuffer string
    var nVolumeNameSize uint64
    var lpVolumeSerialNumber uint64
    var lpMaximumComponentLength uint64
    var lpFileSystemFlags uint64
    var lpFileSystemNameBuffer string
    var nFileSystemNameSize uint32

    kernel32, _ := syscall.LoadLibrary("kernel32.dll")
    getVolume, _ := syscall.GetProcAddress(kernel32, "GetVolumeInformationW")

    var nargs uintptr = 8
    ret, _, callErr := syscall.Syscall9(uintptr(getVolume),
        nargs,
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr(lpRootPathName))),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&lpVolumeNameBuffer)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&nVolumeNameSize)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&lpVolumeSerialNumber)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&lpMaximumComponentLength)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&lpFileSystemFlags)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&lpFileSystemNameBuffer)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&nFileSystemNameSize)),
        0)
    fmt.Println(ret, callErr, lpVolumeNameBuffer)
}
```

... and finally have error :(

```
unexpected fault address 0xffffffffffffffff
fatal error: fault
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0xffffffffffffffff pc=0x456b11]
```

Don't understand and google cant'd help with calling winapi functions and returng string as result.

Thank's.

Comment: You can't pass a `*string` to the Windows API functions and expect Go to magically fill everything in; you need to allocate a buffer of `uint16`s and pass that in instead.

Comment: You are right. Thank you. I changed type of 'lpVolumeNameBuffer' from string to uint16. And change in print to 'string(lpVolumeNameBuffer)'. It returns only one byte, but not the string.

Comment: Of course, because now you're only asking for one byte. Typically you would make a slice and pass a pointer to its first element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Package unsafe](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/)
>
> Package unsafe contains operations that step around the type safety of
>   Go programs.
>
> [type Pointer](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Pointer)
>
> ```
> type Pointer *ArbitraryType
> ```
>
> Pointer represents a pointer to an arbitrary type. There are four
>   special operations available for type Pointer that are not available
>   for other types.
>
> 1) A pointer value of any type can be converted to a Pointer.
>
> 2) A Pointer can be converted to a pointer value of any type.
>
> 3) A uintptr can be converted to a Pointer.
>
> 4) A Pointer can be converted to a uintptr.
>
> Pointer therefore allows a program to defeat the type system and read
>   and write arbitrary memory. It should be used with extreme care.

You failed to heed the warning that `unsafe.Pointer` "should be used with extreme care."

Try this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    var RootPathName = `C:\`
    var VolumeNameBuffer = make([]uint16, syscall.MAX_PATH+1)
    var nVolumeNameSize = uint32(len(VolumeNameBuffer))
    var VolumeSerialNumber uint32
    var MaximumComponentLength uint32
    var FileSystemFlags uint32
    var FileSystemNameBuffer = make([]uint16, 255)
    var nFileSystemNameSize uint32 = syscall.MAX_PATH + 1

    kernel32, _ := syscall.LoadLibrary("kernel32.dll")
    getVolume, _ := syscall.GetProcAddress(kernel32, "GetVolumeInformationW")

    var nargs uintptr = 8
    ret, _, callErr := syscall.Syscall9(uintptr(getVolume),
        nargs,
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr(RootPathName))),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&VolumeNameBuffer[0])),
        uintptr(nVolumeNameSize),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&VolumeSerialNumber)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&MaximumComponentLength)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&FileSystemFlags)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&FileSystemNameBuffer[0])),
        uintptr(nFileSystemNameSize),
        0)
    fmt.Println(ret, callErr, syscall.UTF16ToString(VolumeNameBuffer))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer and example of good practice. It works. Small correct in source. Rootname should be with double slash: var RootPathName = `C:\\`

Comment: @Khoz: Not true. It's a raw string literal. [String literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals): "Raw string literals are character sequences between back quotes, as in `foo`. Within the quotes, any character may appear except back quote. The value of a raw string literal is the string composed of the uninterpreted (implicitly UTF-8-encoded) characters between the quotes; in particular, backslashes have no special meaning and the string may contain newlines."

Comment: Using `unsafe.Pointer` is the only way to use syscalls/winapi and for certain performance aspects, he obviously didn't miss the warning.

Comment: @OneOfOne: Neither I nor the documentation said don't use package `unsafe`. As you can see, I used package `unsafe` in my answer. Therefore your comment and downvote are clearly erroneous. As the documentation clearly explains, "Package `unsafe` contains operations that step around the type safety of Go programs.  `unsafe.Pointer` should be used with extreme care." The package is named `unsafe` for  reason. I didn't say don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact problem you are having but I think it is likely because you are not using the functions in https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/syscall/syscall_windows.go related to converting from the format that comes out of the kernel to what Go needs. Look at other callers to UTF16ToString, like in env_windows.go, to see how they are used.