# Handling LPTSTR in golang with lxn/win

Tags: windows, api, go

I have this piece of code which runs without returning `err` but simply doesn't do its job because it doesn't return the expected value.
The idea is to use [`SHGetSpecialFolderPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/bb762204(v=vs.85).aspx) in order to retrieve the path to the Windows directory (`C:\Windows` for example). This api call has the following signature:

```
BOOL SHGetSpecialFolderPath(
        HWND   hwndOwner, 
        _Out_ LPTSTR lpszPath,
        _In_  int    csidl,
        _In_  BOOL   fCreate );
```

I know it is deprecated, but still available even on current Windows versions. I have to use this API because I need to support Windows versions older than Windows 7 (I know that these are old or even end of life)

This is the piece of code:

```
target := "XXX...XXX" // hard coded string with more than 600 characters
buffer, err := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(target)
if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("conversion of string:", err)
}

result := win.SHGetSpecialFolderPath(0, buffer, win.CSIDL_WINDOWS, false)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("result of get folder:", err)
}

fmt.Println("folder retrieved ok: ", result)
fmt.Println("folder: ", target)
}
```

None of the `err` is set, the API call returns `true` but the string is unchanged:

```
folder retrieved ok:  true
folder: XXX...XXX
```

The result is the same on Windows 10 x64 and on my testing VM running Windows XP SP3 (I know that XP is inherently unsafe)

I have seen examples how to use `LPTRSTR` with `unsafe` and `uintptr` here [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35238933/golang-call-getvolumeinformation-winapi-function) and other sites but none of them compile on my version of golang (which is `go version go1.10.1 windows/amd64`, I compiled with `GOARCH=386`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Approach the problem in a logical, systematic fashion.

---

Carefully read the Microsoft documentation for the function.

[SHGetSpecialFolderPath function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762204.aspx)

---

Carefully read the `lxn/win` package documentation for the function.

[package win](https://godoc.org/github.com/lxn/win)

```
import "github.com/lxn/win"
```

[func SHGetSpecialFolderPath](https://godoc.org/github.com/lxn/win#SHGetSpecialFolderPath)

```
func SHGetSpecialFolderPath(hwndOwner HWND, lpszPath *uint16, csidl CSIDL, fCreate bool) bool
```

---

Now, using the documentation, implement the function call in Go. Go Unicode strings are UTF-8 encoded. Windows Unicode strings are UTF-16 encoded.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"

    "github.com/lxn/win"
)

func main() {
    buf := make([]uint16, win.MAX_PATH)
    rv := win.SHGetSpecialFolderPath(win.HWND(0), &buf[0], win.CSIDL_WINDOWS, false)
    fmt.Println(rv)
    path := syscall.UTF16ToString(buf)
    fmt.Println(path)
}
```

Output:

```
true
C:\Windows
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew the concept from previous experience with C programming but obviously misunderstood the concept of mapping "bytes" to string in Go.