# Get Windows Recognized Environment Variables with Golang

Tags: windows, go, environment-variables

is there a way to get the path of a folder using [Windows Recognized Environment Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/usmt/usmt-recognized-environment-variables) values with Go?

I know Python can do it, but I can't figure it out using Go.
As an example I want ot get the path for the user Downloads folder using `CSIDL_DEFAULT_DOWNLOADS`variable. So, if the user has changed the Downloads folder location by any reason, my code will get the right path, once this variable should store the new, non defaul location.

Thanks for the attention.

P.S.: os.Getenv returns nothing with `CSIDL_DEFAULT_DOWNLOADS` as key.

Comment: Use os.Getenv to read environment variables.

Comment: I wasn't clear on the question before. os.Getenv returns nothing.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49910002/handling-lptstr-in-golang-with-lxn-win

Comment: Thanks that will probably solve my issue. Downloads folder doesn't seem to have a specific variable of its own, but the guid may be the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found for Windows Downloads folder path uses registry package and the folder GUID code.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "golang.org/x/sys/windows/registry"
)

func main() {
    k, err := registry.OpenKey(registry.CURRENT_USER,
        `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders`,
        registry.QUERY_VALUE)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer k.Close()

    s, _, err := k.GetStringValue("{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(s)
}
```